# Login System and Profile Page

Tags: php, authentication

I recently came across this post on Forrst: http://forr.st/~Nbp and thought it'd be a brilliant idea to try and do something similar to the person under the heading: How do I practice to become perfect when I know nothing?

I have used PHP to store user data (username, email, password) and they can login using those details, however I'm a bit stuck on making a profile for a user account and keeping them logged in?

This isn't a specific profile, just something general, like an about me page for example.

Any links or help would be fantastic! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep them logged in you need some mechanism that keeps the information of a specific user between the page requests. I would recommend you to search how to work with cookies and/or to work with sessions. These are used to store information between the page requests.

to make a specific profile for a user, you can use the identifier in your database to get the information out. The identifier would be passed through the URL. Example:

www.site.com/user.php?id=15

This would load a user where the identifier is 15.

Comment: Don't forget about security checks!

Comment: True! I just wanted to explain the main principle :)

Answer (score 1):

The general concept of course would be to use sessions which I assume you've got around already, if not, that's the first thing you would like to do.

The profile pages could use a table in your database with all the info like names, interests and descriptions that would be downloaded from the database on said profile pages.

User avatars could be stored as file in formats $username-avatar.png in some directory, and you would use them as images on the profile pages too.

Answer (score 1):

User authentication is queit simple to integrate if all you need to do is get something up and running. Save all the user records to a DB. Have a login form. Once the info is submitted you ll verify them against a db and if found valid retrieve their member id.

```
$member_id = ValidateUser($username,$password);
```

Store it in a session

```
$_SESSION["member_id"] = $member_id;
```

create a secure function

```
function secure()
{
  if((isset($_SESSION["member_id"])) or ($_SESSION["member_id"] == ""))
  {
    header("location: login.php");
  }
}
```

add this secure function on top of every page.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you want to add an About me section. This is how I will do:

1. Create a table field in your users table(the same table you use to store username, password, etc) called 'about'. The type of this field must be text.
2. You must create an edit profile page where you will have a form with a textarea input. After you click the Submit button you must store the value of this input in the database.
3. If you want to show profile in a page you must use $_GET to retrieve the about information from table users. If you want to show the information in the showprofile.php page, you will go to this url http://yoururl.com/showprofile.php?username=peter

in the showprofile.php you must write:

```
//you must connect to database

<pre>
$user = $_GET["username"];


$query = "select * from users where username='".$user."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


if (mysql_num_rows($query)!=0) {

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo 'About me:';
echo $row['about'];

} 

} else {

echo 'Not found';
}

</pre>
```

To do all these things you must work with sessions or cookies.